# Non-mandatory 'cover letter' in Careers submissions may be better in some cases

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I recently responded to [this job ad](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/109602/sr-backend-engineer-python-java-c-plus-plus-molabs-spiral) which appears to be for a certain company, but actually it turns out it is for a third-party recruiter that represents the described role and other roles.

I ended up spending time on a cover note in the application, but both the third-party recruiter (who has no interest in cover letters) and I would have benefited if this field wasn't mandatory.

In general, I never write cover letters except in special cases, and it was helpful to easily see in the Careers application whether an employer required a cover letter or not.

Rather than a mandatory letter on all applications, would it be more desirable or useful to let the employer decide when it is required?

Comment: This is an aside, but I agree that the job ad was confusing as to who you'd be working for. It does say *IT Recruitment, Technology Staffing* at the top but then at the bottom it talks about creating a new platform so...eh? I don't use Careers (I'm not looking and I don't know if it's worth making a profile if you're not interested in moving) so maybe I missed something that was supposed to make that clear.

Comment: The example job ad is borderline scammy, I'd say. That tiny tag line at the top is a generic category, and since it has "computer software" it's doubtful anyone would think the other stuff on that line ("technology staffing") qualifies the ad in any particular way. Further, the "about" section at the bottom is generally understood to be about the company that is doing the posting. If that's a third-party (in this case ".seed") then the about section should be about .seed, which in theory would explain in detail that it is a recruitment firm.

Comment: Cover letters have always been required. [If you take a look at this screenshot taken in late 2014](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/1R3Q3l3W0g3S2X1W0y0Y/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-19%20at%209.56.56%20PM.png?v=2d6b283f), you can see that the Cover Letter field has an asterisk next to it, denoting it is a required field.

Comment: @Mr.F I would advise re-framing the question to more "_Why_ are cover letters required?" We have this discussion internally, so it would be good to hear other opinions about why people think they shouldn't (or should) be required.

Answer (score -2):

[Hynes already mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2640230/hynes) that a "Cover Letter" has been mandatory for a few years now, when applying to a job on Stack Overflow.

The [listing in question](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/109602/sr-backend-engineer-python-java-c-plus-plus-molabs-spiral) is for a legitimate position, at a legitimate company. We don't allow contingency recruiters on our platform, but recruiting agencies who hire for specific positions are welcome, which is the case with this listing.

We cleaned up the mis-match between the company name on the listing, and the associated company page, so hopefully that clears things up.

Comment: @Talai -- in this case, when this particular recruiter reached out to me, he sent an email containing 6 different job descriptions, only 1 of which was for the stated company. The other 5 were completely unrelated to my interests or background, and when the recruiter called me, he spent time trying to convince me to allow my resume to be submitted to those other jobs. So whatever the ad appeared like when hosted on SO, it was being used simply to solicit resumes for a wide range of behind-the-scenes, other positions not being advertised. I think this is contrary to the usefulness of SO Jobs.

Comment: @Mr.F That behavior isn't acceptable on SO Jobs. The recruiting scenario is allowed only when it's a specific position at a stated company, not for sourcing candidates for other positions. 
We're following up with that recruiter to address this with them.

As for the edits to the listing, it makes it clear that the position is for MoLabs. .seed's company information was a cause for confusion, so we wanted to clear that up. This comes into question because of the way the recruiter handled your interaction, so we're going to work with them to ensure that they adhere to our policies.

Comment: From my point of view, even if a recruiter really is representing a single role and they had been directly authorized to represent it by the hiring company, I still absolutely want to know whether I am agreeing to share my resume with a third-party recruiter or with internal HR/recruiting inside the company. The difference is huge for a lot of reasons (e.g. recruiters are sometimes paid bonuses if they land a candidate with a base salary below a certain level, meaning they truly are not trying to help the candidate get the fairest deal, etc...) so it should be standard to notify about it.

Comment: Wow. SE was all "trust us! We're different" at the beginning of Jobs/Careers. Now that the recruiter money is coming in we can see what they're really made of.

Comment: @AndrewMedico That's really not fair. We can't just not take money from recruiters. The fact is, we require recruiters to disclose the company and the position they're hiring for. Those are VERY onerous requirements for most recruiters. Most choose not to use us when they hear those requirements. We're still better than most job sites as we don't allow any recruiter to get on the platform and spam users with generic job descriptions and vague cattle call messages.